# Can we run an app from xcode 7 to an iPhone with ios 10.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, version

I have updated my iPhone to *ios 10.2* by mistake but I want it to *ios 9.2* because I am working on *xcode7.2* and its *not* supported on ios 10.2. It shows a pop up with this error

> could not find developer disk image

Comment: reinstall your xcode 7.3

Comment: Have you check this one http://www.in.techradar.com/how-to/phone-and-communications/How-to-uninstall-iOS-10-and-downgrade-to-iOS-9/articleshow/54362695.cms

Comment: @NiravD this works only the first 7 days of ios 10 release. Not now.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya There is no effect if he reinstall xcode the problem is that the xcode without the proper Developer disk image doesn't know that there is a new version of iOs

Comment: Better option will be install old Xcode.

Comment: @kelin why should he install old Xcode?

Comment: @mikevorisis, because it allows to support devices with older versions of iOS devices. Even iOS 6 can be supported with appropriate version of Xcode.

Comment: @kelin I agree with you but he has the latest ios version maybe you misunderstood the question

Comment: @mikevorisis, yes, you right.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to downgrade your iPhone or upgrade your xcode, you simple have to insert the 10.2 developer disk image from xcode 8.

I uploaded it [in my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5u6axcq5pizmn2/10.2%20%2814C89%29.zip?dl=0) so you haven't have to download xcode 8.

When you'll download it locate your xcode in application folder -> right-click -Show package contents- -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> IphoneOs.Platform -> DeviceSupport and you will see a lot of folders named 8.0,8.1,8.2 etc. put the file you downloaded it and unzip it.

Now you are good to go.